# What does unique "minimal" partition mean (Context: Partitioning of Vertex-Sets)?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I am studying R. Diestel's Book Graph Theory and I encountered a formulation which I don't quiet understand. Mr. Diestel [speaks in this proof on page 180 (Google Books Link)](http://books.google.de/books?id=aR2TMYQr2CMC&pg=PA182&dq=Lemma%207.4.4%20diestel&hl=de&ei=GNCoTrSkJqPf4QTerLwL&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=snippet&q=7.4.2&f=false) in the second last line of a **unique minimal partition.**

I know what a partition is. And if he speaks of a *unique* partition I understand, that there is no other partition like this one. But what does the word *minimal* mean in this context? Is it, that there is no more refined partition?

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s explicitly defined in the parenthetical remark that follows:

> In other words, if we consider two elements of $C_i$ as equivalent whenever they lie in the same partition set of $C_{ij}$ for every $j\ne i$, then $\mathcal{C}_i$ is the set of equivalence classes.

Among all partitions that refine every partition $\mathcal{C}_{ij}$ with $j\ne i$, this partition $\mathcal{C}_i$ is minimal in the sense that it has the fewest members. Alternatively, it’s the coarsest partition that refines every partition $\mathcal{C}_{ij}$ with $j\ne i$: every other partition that refines every partition $\mathcal{C}_{ij}$ with $j\ne i$ also refines $\mathcal{C}_i$.

Comment: Thank you for your alternative explanation! Helped me a lot!